# How can I run a command remotely on an Azure machine with powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to run the command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName AzMachine1 -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock{Test-Path $path}
```

on an Azure machine. However, it returns the following error "Connecting to remote server AzMachine1 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client received an HTTP
status code of 504 from the remote WS-Management service". I've checked if the service WinRM is running and working correctly and everything seams fine.

I'm not sure if the command Invoke-Command works on Azure machines. Can someone confirm this?

I also looked into the module Az.Compute and the command

```
 Invoke-AzVMRunCommand
```

Which of these commands is the best one to run the command Test-Path remotely?

Comment: Check the explanation about getting started with running scripts in general within Azure VMs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command). They mention PowerShell there, but mainly discuss the capabilities/limitations of using the functionality which [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-6.3.0) uses.

Comment: The cmdlet expects the script referenced in the -ScriptPath parameter to be local to where the cmdlet is being run. It's for running scripts, not commands.

Answer (score 0):

Running PowerShell remote commands on an Azure VM is possible, but there is some configuration required.

See Microsoft's instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/winrm

Comment: I don't have access to some parameters that the command needs, which makes things a bit more difficult. But is it normal that the command Invoke-Command does not work with machines in Azure?

Comment: To clarify, Invoke-Command can work on VMs in Azure, assuming the WinRM services has been configured on the VM in Azure, the firewalls between your client and Azure allow the connection, and your WinRM client has been appropriately configured. 

The alternative to WinRM is Invoke-AzVMRunCommand, which uses the CustomScriptExtension to execute a command offline on the VM. The script you submit to execute can query an external service (ex: Azure Table Storage or a web service) to get run time parameter values.

Comment: Oh okay, I wasn't sure that the Invoke-Command worked on Azure Vms, because it returns this error message "The WinRM client received an HTTP status code of 504 from the remote WS-Management service", can you help me understand what this means? I've checked and the service is running properly. Not sure why this is happening is it the firewall. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you are getting an HTTP 504, you are connecting to the WinRM service on your Azure VM--so the issue is likely a configuration of the WinRM service or your client.

Comment: Do you think reconfiguring the WinRM will fix the problem?